# Meta-analysis using experimental reliability data

Tags: hypothesis-testing, meta-analysis, reliability, measurement-error

I have a rather conceptual question. We measured experimentally the reliability of a certain readout. 
Now what I would like to do is to use this data to give a statement about the results of previous studies using this readout.

As an example these (rather simple studies) have two groups with a certain mean and SD, and a difference of the mean e.g. "by" an intervention. They compared these two means using a T-Test.

How can I now prove using our experimental test-retest reliability that their statement that the differences are not equal is (not) valid?

***The parameters I (or R) calculated for intrarater reliability were:***

- *ICC (Agreement):*  0.638 (0.44, 0.777)
- *within subject coefficient of variation:*  0.084 (0.069, 0.102)
- *Smallest detectable difference:* 0.233 (0.191,   0.285)

I was also thinking about a model, however I don`t see yet how it helps with the problem above.

***Previous studies published outcomes like that:***

108.1±33.6 (SEM) versus 78.2±29.4 (SEM) mm3, P=0.048, n=10, unpaired, 2-tailed Student’s t test

EDIT:
While waiting for answers, I found a question going in the same direction here:  [Statistical Tests with Data Having Measurement Errors](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/51510/statistical-tests-with-data-having-measurement-errors) , and here: [Statistical Tests That Incorporate Measurement Uncertainty](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/58371/statistical-tests-that-incorporate-measurement-uncertainty?rq=1)

However the basic conceptual question is, does it really make a difference if I include a measurement error into the values observed by others, as it is already included into the observerd SD? However it should be possible to give an idea about fraction of SD being measurement error or the consequence of other factors. Somehow?

**EDIT:**

I tried now two different approaches (see detail below), maybe someone could comment on that:

1. Effect of reliability on statistical power using Monte Carlo simulations

(Kanyongo, Gibbs Y.; Brook, Gordon P.; Kyei-Blankson, Lydia; and Gocmen, Gulsah (2007) "Reliability and Statistical Power: How Measurement Fallibility A ects Power and Required Sample Sizes for Several Parametric and Nonparametric Statistics," Journal of Modern Applied Statistical Methods: Vol. 6: Iss. 1, Article 9)

2. Effect of reliability on beta-estimate using SIMEX. (e.g.[http://www.statistik.lmu.de/~helmut/Texte/Simex_Rnews.pdf)](http://www.statistik.lmu.de/~helmut/Texte/Simex_Rnews.pdf)

Both methods have their (dis-)advantages.

For 1 I used the following parameters from systematic analysis of the literatur: 
 A. Pooled effect of (neuroprotective) treatment, ctrl. vs. treatment 
 B. Pooled SD, mean of the published SDs. 
 C. Reliability of own replicated measurements, ICC.

with B and C I calculated the true SD, and than looked for the effects of different reliabilities on Power/Sample size, using the program MC2G (Brooks, 2002). (too lazy to implement in R)

Problems with this method is: the (self measured) intrarater ICC is also dependent on the measured inter subject variance, therefore its usage to describe a true SD from others seems odd. 
**Has anyone a better idea what parameter to use?**

For the Simex- method: This works quite nice, using the R package "simex". 
The parameters i used here 
 1. Simulate two population:
      a. one control group (mean=1; SD=pooled SD for controls, n= mean sample size)
      b. one treatment group (mean=1 + pooled effect; SD=pooled SD for treatments, n= mean sample size)
2. The SD of the measurement error: here I am quite unsure: what  I used was the SD of the intra-subject differences in our own studies. (? is that correct?)

With this method two problems occur: 
a. as the pooled power of the publications is 40 % the effects of the simulations differ a lot, of course. 
b. see above I am not sure if my interpretation of the SD of the measurement error is correct.

Last but not least I am not sure how to discuss the relationship between both approaches.

Comment: Can you provide a simple example dataset for the reliabilities & the descriptive statistics & results from the prior study?

Comment: Thanks gung, I edited the question. Is that sufficient?

Comment: Any suggestions how I can make this question more interesting/useful/understandable/ meaningful?

Comment: I don't know. The edit will bump it on the main page, which may bring more attention.

Comment: Well  i guess its the typical problem of a  case of a non-statician posing a question...